# Wanna Use this library for a small project

Tags: cryptonight

Hope someones here, I wanna ask if what are the parameters in [this](https://github.com/sumoprojects/cryptonight-hash-lib/blob/master/cryptonite_hash.c#L315) code, in line 315:

```
void cryptonight_hash(void* output, const void* input, const int aes_ni_supported) {
    struct cryptonight_ctx *ctx = (struct cryptonight_ctx*)malloc(sizeof(struct cryptonight_ctx));

    if (aes_ni_supported) {
        cryptonight_hash_ctx_aes_ni(output, input, 76, ctx);
    }
    else
    {
        cryptonight_hash_ctx(output, input, 76, ctx);
    }
    free(ctx);
}
```

What is the `input` and `output` parameter, I havn't read that on my journey here. How do I form a code to get it? where did it came from?

Answer (score 1):

`input` is the block data you want to hash.

`output` is where the resulting hash will be stored.

`aes_ni_supported` is a flag to indicate whether the machine running the code has a processor with AES-NI support.